# Centering ul inside container with responsive web design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

So I'm trying to keep an unordered list centered once the website hits a certain media query. I can't get it to stay in the center of it's container if the page is moved around. Here is the corresponding code.

HTML

```
<div id="centerNav">

  <ul id="home-nav">
    <li><a href="/practice-areas/dui-defense/">DUI/DWI Defense</a></li>
    <li><a href="/practice-areas/criminal-defense/">Criminal Defense</a></li>
    <li><a href="/practice-areas/estate-planning/">Estate Planning</a></li>
    <li style="border: none;"><a href="/practice-areas/agricultural-law/"> Agricultural Law</a></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

CSS

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 839px) 
{
#centerNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 840px;
    padding: 0;
    height:60px;
}

#home-nav li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 158px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    margin-top: 8px;
    line-height: 1em;
    padding-left: 10px;
 }

#home-nav {
    list-style:none;
    position:relative;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 5;
    border-top: 4px double #fff; 
    border-bottom: 4px double #fff;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    background: #7a0426;
}

}
```

Comment: is it correct to assume you want to center #centerNav or did you want to center the ul?

Comment: I want to center the group of the li's basically. I thought I could put them inside a container to accomplish that, but I'm stuck.

Comment: your li are floating that's why they are not centered, if you can setup a http://www.jsfiddle.net that would be helpful to people answering this question

Comment: I took the float out and it still isn't moving. Should I margin: 0 auto the ul?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `float` from li and make it `display: inline-block`

I think this will solve your issue.

**css**

```
#centerNav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 840px;
    padding: 0;
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
}

#home-nav li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    background: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    line-height: 60px;
    padding:0 10px;
 }
```

[jsFiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/hsPjd/)

Comment: It still sits on the left of the page. Here is the link to the site. http://prokellseo.com/testdomian/haden-byrne/

Comment: 1) remove float from li, no, do float: none for this media query. 2) text-align: center on the ul for this media query width

Comment: can you please apply my css, please check the jsFiddle file for help

Comment: okay can you look at the site again. It's moving them but they're backward now?

Comment: I don't know what you did with your html but I am seeing your html structure for that nav like this ul > div > li which is invalid markup

Comment: For me removing the float and adding display: inline-block to the li Works perfectly., thanks.-

Answer (score 0):

In your media query you need to make sure float is none because you have float set from previous css

```
#home-nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The unordered list that contains the li, add text-align: center

```
#home-nav {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Also your html structure is currently invalid because you have a div as the immediate child of a ul. You can wrap the ul with the div if you need to but it definitely should not be the way it is now

That should solve the issue